# Get final url after all redirects in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url

I have url generated from pagination:

```
$next = $articles->nextPageUrl();
```

However this new url always leads to redirect. For SEO reasons i need to put there final url (generated after all redirects). How can i achieve this properly in Laravel?

E.g. Url generated by nextPageUrl() is `/page/83?page=4`, however it redirects to `/blog?page=4`. I should somehow get `/blog?page=4`.

How can i achieve this properly in Laravel?

Comment: I cannot see how the url generated by the `nextPageUrl()` leads to redirect. It just adds `page` query param to the current path. Can you clarify?
`dd($users->nextPageUrl()); // http://example.com/path?page=2`

Comment: Pagination actually doesn't matter at all. Question is more general.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$articles->lastPage()` paginator method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#paginator-instance-methods

Comment: I don't need last page of paginator, i need url generated after redirects, e.g. url generated from next page is /articles?page=3, and it redirects to /blog/3, i should somehow get /blog/3.

Answer (score 0):

In this method you need to declare input type Page

Example : 
[image: As You shown in My Project i have given filename]

Just follow this Steps
In your Controller

```
 $namefile = $request->get('filename');
 return view('BladeFilename')->with('filename', $namefile);
```

Just change $request get to whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to manually trace the redirect (5.4 version syntax):

```
// Call the given Closure / class@method and inject its dependencies.
$redirect = App::call('App\Http\Controllers\SomeController@someMethodWithRedirect');

/** @var RedirectResponse $redirect */
$redirect->getTargetUrl();
```

This approach wouldn't fit if the called functions aren't pure (does any DB persisting, etc).

Comment: I thought maybe there would be something like `\Url::getFinalUrl($url)`, looks like there is nothing like this.